# SSIS FTP Task problem with UNIX server

Tags: ssis

I would like to ask if there's a known issue with the FTP Task of SSIS 2005 on UNIX servers(HP UX B.11.23.). As per checking, we were able to ftp files on Windows Server but not on Unix. Though I can browse the ftp path of the UNIX server from my windows exlporer. I can even manually copy files. But when I tried uploading file thru SSIS FTP task, it does'nt work. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does the UNIX server use SFTP or FTPES instead of FTP?  Is the FTP site locked down on IP address?  These are pretty common reasons why FTP doesn't in SSIS out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:
Try using a client with a visible log pane to connect (e.g. FileZilla). If that fails then it might give you a stronger idea of what's wrong, or at least where to start looking.
Try a telnet to the server and make sure it's behaving as you would expect it to.  Example [here](http://piotrkosoft.net/pub/mirrors/ftp.wu-ftpd.org/telnet.testing.HOWTO).